# Как построить правильный SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть такие данные в таблице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2рая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
также есть такой SQL запрос

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`value` AS `modelnumber` FROM `purchase_wizard_purchase_list` AS `main_table`LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` ON `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`attribute_id`=159 AND `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`entity_id` LIKE `main_table`.`product_id`
```

Но оно не ищет.Как можно решить такую проблему?

PHP код

```
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
        'catalog_product_entity_varchar'=>'catalog_product_entity_varchar'),
        '`catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`attribute_id`=159 AND `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`entity_id` LIKE `main_table`.`product_id`',
        array('modelnumber'=>'value'));
```

Использую фреймворк magento2

Comment: Приведите хотя бы текст ошибки. Наверное, у вас в запросе указаны несуществующие таблицы. Например, что такое `\` main_table\``? (обратите внимание на пробел)

Comment: Ошибки нету. Оно возвращает null

Comment: Сделайте миграцию для обеих таблиц, и скиньте сюда, чтобы все понимали о чем вы спрашиваете (можно без самих данных) либо хотя бы скриншоты не данных, а там где свойства полей. Ну и напишите конкретно что хотите получить в конечном итоге.

Comment: И на php вы пользуетесь каким то построить едем запросов...хотелось бы знать каким (или фреймворком)

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Если запрос получается в точности такой, как вы написали (left join и все до единого условия в ON, а не в where) от запрос в любом случае обязан дать все записи из main_table даже если для них ничего не найдено во второй. Если ничего не возвращает, то либо результирующий запрос ни такой, либо возникает ошибка БД которую от вас скрывает какой то из слоев доступа к БД.

Comment: А что касается LIKE то он ищет строки по маске. причем любые символы в ней обозначаются `%`. И строка '31850' никак не может быть like строке '[31850], [31851], ...'. Вот если бы было наоборот, да еще с процентами, вот тогда бы нашло. т.е. что то вроде `'[31850], [31851], ...' like '%31850%'` так что если хотите так искать то меняйте поля местами и добавляйте проценты. Но вообще структуру БД надо менять, нельзя данные хранить в одном поле через запятую, SQL не рассчитан на работу с такими данными. Данные должны быть развернуты отдельными строками в дополнительной таблице